# Thermostat has two wires going into C terminal

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, nest

Trying to help my dad install his new Nest thermostat - for some reason his *thermostat* has two wires going into the C terminal.  I've searched and cannot find any other question about a setup like this.

I'm wondering what kind of system may have caused this?

My thought is to abandon the C wires altogether and just install the Nest without them, since apparently it's not required.

[image: Thermostat wiring]

Comment: One of the wires going into the C terminal is white -- what color is the other wire?  Also, what do you have for an HVAC system?

Comment: Not at my dad's place right now so can't check the other color. It's a forced air natural gas furnace and central air. There's also an electric air cleaner with the furnace.  Would it be wrong to pigtail the two c wires together?

Comment: The current setup is the equivalent of a pigtail.

Comment: @Darrrrrren -- when you get back to your dad's place, can you check and see how many thermostat wires there are at the furnace?

Comment: @bib, yes, but the nest only allows one wire into each terminal. To get both of these in I'd have to pigtail them externally.